# Why did "pigeon" replace the native word "culver"?

Tags: etymology, historical-change, old-english, sociolinguistics, ornithology

*Pigeon* is a borrowing from Anglo-Norman where the etymons are French *pigon, pigeon*. The earliest citation is found in Middle English, from 1375 per *OED*:

> 1375
> Thomas Blont..hath indowed Dame Isabell..with..the thridde pejone of the grete dovehouse. 
> <sub>in A. H. Cooke, *Early History of Mapledurham* (1925) 204</sub>
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*, s.v. “pigeon, n., sense I.1.a”, September 2023. 
> https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/1036744913</sub>

[*Etymonline*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/pigeon) gives the etymology of pigeon as below and mentions that the word *pigeon* replaced *culver*:

> late 14c., *pijoun*, "a dove, a young dove" (early 13c. as a surname), from Old French *pijon, pigeon* "young dove" (13c.), probably from Vulgar Latin **pibionem*, dissimilation from Late Latin *pipionem* (nominative *pipio*) "squab, young chirping bird" (3c.), from *pipire* "to peep, chirp," a word of imitative origin. As an English word it replaced *culver* (Old English *culufre*, from Vulgar Latin **columbra*, from Latin *columbula*) and native dove (n.).

*Culver* is an earlier native word for a pigeon, a dove; from Old English *culfre, culufre*.  *OED* mentions that *culver* was once common and the latest citation given is from 1869:

> **a.** A dove, a pigeon. 
> Formerly a common name for the wood pigeon in the south and east of England.
>
> 1869
> The lark, the thrush, the culver too. 
> <sub>R. Browning, *Ring & Book* vol. IV. xii. 218</sub>
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*, s.v. “culver, n.¹, sense a”, July 2023. 
>  https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/4890785183</sub>

*Culver* is a dialectal or a poetic word now and it appears to be used only in the UK.

> (*now UK, south and east dialect or poetic*) A dove or pigeon, now specifically of the species *Columba palumbus*.
>
> *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/culver)*

What happened in history that the word *pigeon* replaced *culver*?

*Pigeon* is an Anglo-Norman borrowing. Could it be that Anglo-Normans had an influence on the field of ornithology within that period and were French words often borrowed into the avian terminology; or could it be that they were interested in the domestication of pigeons and these interactions influenced the language? I'm speculating about the possible sociolinguistic or science-influenced factors but there can be other linguistic or historical factors of course.

Comment: There is also "dove" which is Germanic (so may have been in Old English) but is not attested until c. 1200. And Scots had "columbe" from the 15th century.

Comment: A lot of English words for meats are based on French (beef/cow, pork/swine, mutton/sheep) and sometimes this carried over to the live animals (poultry).  *Pigeon* may be an example of the latter.

Comment: The OED maintains that it is of unknown origin, casting doubt on Etymonline’s story: “Old English *culfre* weak feminine (and ? *culfer* strong feminine), not known in the other Germanic languages. By Grimm thought to be derived < Latin *columba*; but even if we take *culufre* as an earlier form (in which we are hardly justified), it is not easy to connect this phonetically with the Latin word. The thoroughly popular standing of the name is also against its adoption < Latin.”

Comment: @Henry I've found in Anglo-Norman dictionary that pigeon (French _pigon_) served as a dish is from 1396: https://www.anglo-norman.net/entry/pejon

Comment: @TimR Good find. It can be a possible answer with details. I believe the English nobility used Anglo-Norman as their main language after the Norman invasion of 1066.

Comment: @StuartF Yes, _OED_ says that _dove_ is a word inherited from Germanic but it says in the etymology that "Old English _*dufe_, not found (unless as first element in _dúfe-doppa_: see dive-dap n.). However, _OED_ also adds that "In Old English the name was displaced by _culufre_".

Comment: @tchrist Yes, _OED_ says of unknown origin for _culver_ but it is attested in Old English as _culfre, culufre, culefre_ and _culfer_ per _OED_. It also says that _culver_ was commonly used for the wood pigeon in the south and east of England. And I've just found out in _OED_ that the name of the bird _dove_ was displaced by _culufre_ in Old English also.

Comment: My go-to Old English source is the Anglo-Saxon Gospels (with a Northumbrian gloss).  For example [Luke 3:22](https://archive.org/details/gospelaccording00skeagoog/page/n60/mode/2up?view=theater) has *culfre/culfra* at Jesus's baptism, with plural *culfran/culfras* in  [Luke 2:24](https://archive.org/details/gospelaccording00skeagoog/page/n50/mode/2up?view=theater) for Jesus's presentation.

Answer (score 1):

Quotes from a text presenting [History of Netheravon Dovecote](https://www.english-heritage.org.uk/visit/places/netheravon-dovecote/history/):

> Till 1761, the construction of a dovecote was one of the privileges associated with lordship, they are often found near castles and manor houses and considered a symbol of power of the owner of surrounding land.

> Although the Romans are known to have reared pigeons, there is no
> evidence that they introduced them to Britain.

> It is more likely that they were another introduction of the Norman nobility and, indeed, pigeons and dovecotes are mentioned in the Domesday Book of 1086. Other documentary and archaeological evidence suggests that they were used extensively by the Normans (*pigeons dropping were used as a fertilizer*).

The word "pigeon" may have been imported by Anglo-Normans as a consequence of this practice.

Comment: Thank you. Good find! I've suspected an explanation like this also but I couldn't find a good reference.